# Detaching doctrine entities that are part of a relationship

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm developing a Doctrine application where I have a one-to-many relationship between two entities, which I'll call 'Foo' and 'Bar'.  'Bar' is the owning side of the relationship, which might seem strange in this context.  I need to process all bars belonging to a foo one after the other and flush the changes.  However, the bar entities are very substantial in size (several megabytes each).  Since there can be many bars for each foo, a trivial loop will eat up all my RAM.  I'm trying to solve this by flushing and detaching after every bar has been processed and flushed, like so:

```
foreach ($foo->getBars() as $bar) {
    $bar->setSomething(...potentially large blobs...);
    // ... dozens of more setters (and getters)
    $em->flush();
    // or: $em->flush($bar);
    $em->detach($bar);
}

// unrelated code
$foo->setDoStuff(...)
$em->flush();
```

However this fails badly on the second iteration, because for some reason the second flush() will encounter the first bar in the object graph and complain that it has not been persisted (it is unmanaged).  The error message is: "A new entity was found through the relationship 'Foo#bars' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity"

If I only flush the specific $bar, instead of all entities, the loop completes successfully, but makes it impossible to ever use $em->flush() without arguments again later on, since it will then encounter those unmanaged entities.

Detaching $foo would solve this, but this is unfortunately not acceptable, because there are many other references to $foo in the code which might want to modify and flush it later on.

How would I solve this problem?  All examples in the docs related to clear()/detach() seem to be quite trivial and do not involve relationships.

Ideally there would be a way to revert objects back into their non-hydrated proxy lazy-loading state, like the ones obtained by $em->getReference().  The garbage collector would then free up the memory previously used by all the fields.

Comment: If the specific flush is not persisting other entities maybe you could try using cascade? Anyway if memory is a big concern maybe loading each is not the best option, you could load the bar IDs for foo first and in the loop load each bar separately and the unset it.

Comment: @mickadoo The problem is not that things don't get flushed.  But the second part of your comment hints in a good direction, I will investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this for my specific use case, however it seems that a very generic, beautiful, works-everywhere solution to this is just not possible.

The important thing to understand is how Doctrine will load entities and build an entire graph of objects having references to each other.  In order to properly detach any entity, there *must not* be any references to it anywhere.  This is possible to do if programming very carefully, but in general it's hard to guarantee that some unrelated part of the code didn't obtain a reference to the entity to detach, or worse, didn't attached it to the entity graph.  Doctrine will traverse this graph on every flush operation and find any referenced entities, even the detached ones.

The actual problem in my code above is that `$foo->getBars()` initializes a collection that will end up containing references to all 'Bar' entities.  On every flush, Doctrine will encounter `$foo` in its identity map and `$foo` references this materialized collection of 'Bar', which in turn references the 'Bar' entities themselves.  And thus it will try to flush them again.

My solution was this: I completely avoid the use of collections and fetch the 'Bar' entities one by one to make sure nothing else references them.  Something along those lines:

```
$sql = "SELECT b.id FROM Bar b WHERE b.foo = :foo";
$rows = $em->createQuery($sql)->setParameter('foo', $foo)->getScalarResult();
$repository = $this->em->getRepository('Bar');
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $bar = $repository->find($row['id']);
    $bar->setSomething(...potentially large blobs...);
    // ... dozens of more setters (and getters)
    $em->flush($bar);
    $em->detach($bar);
}

// unrelated code can now safely flush, because there are no references to any 'Bar'
// in the entity graph
$foo->setDoStuff(...)
$em->flush();
```

But this only works if no other part of the code has called `$foo->getBars()` before, or loaded a 'Bar' objects and plans to reuse them later on.